# DBus Glib with C++: Can't create a DBusGProxy, release it and create that again

Tags: c++, c, glib, dbus

I'm working on a lib that uses Glib internally to connect to other modules.

This lib has a initialize method that sets up the dbus connection and a terminate method that finalizes all the internal resources (including the dbus connection).
At least it should do this.

However, I can't make dbus calls again after the terminate method gets called (of course I called the initialize method again before calling the dbus methods again).

I'm using C++ mainly (a few used libs are in C).

Here is my internal dbus initializer:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

#include <dbus/dbus-glib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define _DBUS_SERVICE       "Removed due to restrictions"
#define _DBUS_PATH      "/"
#define _DBUS_INTERFACE "Removed due to restrictions"

static DBusGConnection * my_dbus_conn = NULL;
static DBusGProxy * my_proxy = NULL;

gboolean dbus_init() {
    GError *error = NULL;
    g_type_init();
    my_dbus_conn = dbus_g_bus_get(DBUS_BUS_SESSION, &error);
    if (my_dbus_conn == NULL) {
        g_printerr("DBUS Connection Error (%s)\n", error->message);
        g_error_free(error);
        return false;
    }
    my_proxy = dbus_g_proxy_new_for_name(my_dbus_conn, _DBUS_SERVICE, _DBUS_PATH, _DBUS_INTERFACE);
    if (my_proxy == NULL) {
        g_printerr("ERROR: DBUS Proxy creation Error (%s)\n", error->message);
        g_error_free(error);
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

DBusGProxy * dbus_get_proxy() {
    if (my_proxy == NULL) {
        dbus_init();
    }
    return my_proxy;
}

void dbus_term() {
    g_object_unref(G_OBJECT (my_proxy));
    dbus_g_connection_unref(my_dbus_conn);
    my_dbus_conn = NULL;
}

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

Here is my calling code:

```
MY_G_DEBUG("Manager", "Creating Server IPC stub...");
this->m_pDbusServer = get_proxy();

if (this->m_pDbusServer == NULL) {
    return;
}

MY_G_DEBUG("Manager", "CheckPoint 1!");
gboolean success;
GError *gerror = NULL;
char **l_pHelloWorldReply;

success = dbus_server_helloworld(this->m_pDbusServer, "Hello World from Manager", &l_pHelloWorldReply, &gerror);

MY_G_DEBUG("Manager", "CheckPoint 2!");

if (success == FALSE) {
    MY_G_DEBUG("Manager", "CheckPoint 3!");
    if (gerror == NULL) {
        MY_G_DEBUG("Manager", "CRITICAL: Hello World call Failed (error not set)");
    } else {
        MY_G_DEBUG("Manager", "CRITICAL: Hello World call Failed (%s)", gerror->message);
        g_error_free(gerror);
        gerror = NULL;
    }
    return;
} else {
    MY_G_DEBUG("Manager", "CheckPoint 4!");
    for (guint ii = 0; l_pHelloWorldReply[ii] != NULL; ii++) {
        MY_G_DEBUG("Manager", "Hello World response %d: %s", ii, l_pHelloWorldReply[ii]);
    }
}

MY_G_DEBUG("Manager", "CheckPoint 5!");
```

Here is the logging output:

```
(process:24498): Manager-DEBUG: Checkpoint: 1!
(process:24498): Manager-DEBUG: Checkpoint: 2!
(process:24498): Manager-DEBUG: Checkpoint: 3!
(process:24498): Manager-DEBUG: CRITICAL: Hello World call Failed (error not set)
```

I got an error message everytime I call the dbus_term function, however I couldn't manage to fix it.

```
(process:24498): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: invalid uninstantiatable type `<invalid>' in cast to `GObject'
(process:24498): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_unref: assertion `G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
```

The first time I try to call methods, everything works well...
I strongly believe that's caused by the dbus_term issue.

Does anyone have any idea why that is happening?

Thanks very much.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Don't use dbus-glib in new code, use GDBus instead.

GDBus is the new dbus api in glib 2.26. Its advantages over dbus-glib include the use of the GIO async patterns (GAsync*, GCancellable), the use of GVariant for variant types and better threading support.

See 
http://library.gnome.org/devel/gio/2.28/ch29.html for migrating to GDBus.

Comment: I've been told that recently at the glibDbus mail list.
I'm working on this GDBus migration.
Thanks very much for you answer.

Comment: You didn't answer the question.

Answer (score 1):

It is a bug to drop the last reference to a dbus connection that is still open. One of the problems with the bindings that you are using is that it is difficult to know when the connection actually closes. It is somewhat unsatisfying, but it has been my practice to leave one reference around on connections to a well known bus like the session bus.

Comment: Nice to hear that. I'd realize that it was not possible to determine that. I'm migrating to GDBus now... I'm also using sockets to do some communication between processes. GlibDBus caused me a lot of trouble. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: So, what is the solution?

Comment: At least to my reading this does answer the question.  His question was of the type, "Why am I getting this error?"  My response tells him that he is getting an error because he has written a bug, and further what the bug is.  To clarify, as I recall his call to dbus_term brings the ref count on the session bus to 0 while the dbus lib is still writing the bus in the background.  This leaves the dbus lib's internal data structures in a bad state so the next attempt to use the session bus fails.  The solution is to hold one reference to the session bus around till the program closes.